# Certificate enrollment for Local system failed to enroll Event ID:13

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, certificate-authority

I've just finished installing a second domain controller to gain redundancy in the network. (and to solve some issues) After installation and configuring all errors are gone but one that is:

> Event Id 13: Certificate enrollment for Local system failed to enroll
>   for a DomainController certificate with request ID N/A from [CA NAME]
>   (The RPC server is unavailable. 0x800706ba (WIN32: 1722)).

The first DC has the ECA installed. That action caused some problems I asked about in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/411270/slow-starting-domain-controller-after-installing-enterprise-certificate-authorit) thread and was the trigger for installing the second DC.

Normally its not to hard to find a solution for an error with a well-known event id. But Google for this error gives me a lot of different solution so I thought it might be a better idea to ask here hoping someone recognises the problem.

Edit:
Left the server alone for the weekend because I heard that certificate propagation can sometimes be slow in starting up / functioning properly. 
Today I noticed that certificate enrolment was working without changing anything. I'm going to monitor it to see if it keeps working.

Comment: Sounds an awful lot to me like your CA isn't reachable from (or set up properly to issue certificates, perhaps?) to the new machine.

Comment: Hi, and thanks! Well everything is possible I've only installed ECA (add the role). The second DC is only added to the forest so I didn't do anything there with ECA? Can you think of a step I could have forgotten?

Comment: Well, that error basically says "I can't get the certificate you told me to get from the CA you told me to get it from."  So, the first thing I'd do is check to see if maybe it already has the certificate it's requesting (which could cause the enrollment to fail), make sure the CA machine is properly configured to issue the type of certificate being requested, and that a firewall or whatever between the two servers isn't blocking the request or transmission.

Comment: Hi, I left the server alone this weekend because one of the theories I read about this problem is that propagation of these certificates can be slow. I just looked and I noticed that Certificates Are being enrolled now. As a test I also restarted the DC and this time it came up without the errors. I'm going to monitor it a bit but for now it looks solved. Thanks for thinking with me. :)