# Certificate Error on Server 2008 R2 Event ID 6 and 13

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, ad-certificate-services

I have two DC, one is a Windows Server 2003 (certificate server), the other is Windows Server 2008 R2.
The Windows Server 2008 R2 has the following events in the event viewer.

```
Source: Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-AutoEnrollment
Event ID: 6
Automatic certificate enrollment for local system failed (0x800706ba) The RPC server is unavailable.
```

And

```
Source: Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-CertEnroll
Event ID: 13
Certificate enrollment for Local system failed to enroll for a DomainController certificate with request ID N/A from 2003DCinternal.domain.com\DOMAIN-Root-CA.domain.com (The RPC server is unavailable. 0x800706ba (WIN32: 1722)).
```

I've read a few things over the internet:
 [Certificate enrollment for Local system failed to enroll Event ID:13](https://serverfault.com/questions/411568/certificate-enrollment-for-local-system-failed-to-enroll-event-id13) 
Seems to indicate that I should check if I already have a certificate installed. I open the `Certificates MMC Snap-in` on the 2008 R2 server having the errors and go to `Personal` > `Certificates`. From there I see a certificate for localhost issued by localhost (could that indicate a part of my problem?).

I've also seen other stuff indicating that 2003 servers can not generate the correct certificates for 2003 or Windows 7 computers.

Other than that Google doesn't really have any thing that solidly explains what the issue is.

Could someone help me understand how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is there a firewall between the two machines?

Comment: @RyanRies There is not

Answer (score 1):

You might find the following link useful as a troubleshooting reference http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2007/11/06/how-to-troubleshoot-certificate-enrollment-in-the-mmc-certificate-snap-in.aspx .

Incidentally, the self signed cert issued by localhost is not the problem.

Personally, I'd take a network trace from the 2008 R2 DC while manually trying to enrol for a cert using the MMC from the 2008R2 DC and see how far you get.